# Are official transcripts required for faculty appointment?

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, transcript-of-records

I am curious if faculty appointees (at various levels) should request their schools to send their official transcripts to the employer to get a faculty position? Or is it only required for students?

When I finish my PhD, do I still need to request my school to send an official transcript of my PhD for starting an assistant professor position (and later on)?

Comment: I just got a faculty position and the university's adminstration asked for my **middle school diploma** (*brevet* in French). They relented after I protested and I only had to send my PhD diploma. Assume the worst.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I was not required to show any kind of official academic documentation, diploma or transcript.

Comment: @Bitwise you mean the HR didn't have any document from you on file? Where has it been?

Comment: @Googlebot I believe they just wanted my ID. Why would they need my diploma? I guess it is theoretically possible that someone would leave mid graduate studies, still get accepted to a good postdoc lab, get fellowships/grants and do a good enough job in order to get a faculty position, all without anyone noticing they don't have a diploma. But I haven't ever heard of such a case (it is a small country though).

Comment: I was required to bring the original of my degree plus arrange for the Registrar of the Uni. where I completed my degree to send a formal memo confirming the granting of the degree.  But no transcripts.

Comment: When I accepted my faculty position a few months ago, they asked for my dissertation approval form until my official transcript could be sent (after my start date).

Answer (score 9):

In the United States, at least, the norm is that you send official transcripts once you are offered the job.  At my university (and I believe by SACS regulation) the transcript(s)/degree(s) must be on file with the university for all faculty members, thus it is a requirement to be able to get the job.

During the application process, though, unofficial transcripts are generally sufficient, if they even ask for it.  Sending official transcripts to 100 different places in the application process would get very expensive, very quickly. For example, if they wanted from every post-secondary school I had attended, I would need to request transcripts from no less than 8 different universities, some of which would just have a course or two I took in summer programs abroad or were unrelated to my field. Even if they only needed my terminal degree, at $10/transcript, it adds up fast in addition to being a gigantic hassle for everyone involved.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

In my experience, I was required to list my degrees with where & when I obtained them. I was not required to get the official transcripts sent but I was also hired on where I completed graduate school (so they already had official transcripts on record).

My guess is that there is no single answer for **ALL** academic institutions across. My advice: submit the unofficial and be prepared to obtain official if needed (but you already knew that).

Comment: *I was also hired on where I completed graduate school (so they already had a record).* I am envious of the optimism contained in this sentence. I was once told, when trying to renew my yearly registration as a PhD  student, to go fetch a document from the next office over, because they couldn't get it, it's a different department... More seriously, given privacy laws and regulations, I would be surprised if what you think happened really happened.

Comment: When I was offered a job by the same department where I had earlier gotten my PhD, the department chair told me I needed to have an official transcript sent to the university.  My response was, "Really?  Even though you gave me the degree, you need me to pay $5 to another office on the same campus to officially tell you that you did it?"  The department chair was apparently embarrassed enough by this that he spent weeks jumping through administrative hoops in order to avoid inflicting that trivial inconvenience on me.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I actually had to do this one year.  I audited a course where I teach and took a fitness class for credit (because I'm too old for Bs and that motivated me to go) and the next year I was required to provide an official transcript =\  Thankfully where I teach we seem to be one of the few places that still provide free transcripts.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi 
Thank you for your perspective but your comment "I would be surprised if what you think happened really happened" is wholly unnecessary.  I've already acknowledged that my specific experience is unlikely to be replicated but it did happen so it could happen again.  And yes, I've verified how it happened.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yup.  One of my students applied to the master's program in the same department where she earned her baccalaureate degree.  When she hadn't heard anything for a while I checked.  The graduate office explained that *they were waiting for her undergraduate transcript.*

Comment: @BobBrown  Thanks for that. That sounds very frustrating.  We're very fortunate here at my university for the way they've streamlined and prevented those occurrences.  I'm sure those things that you and Najibdrissi mention happen all the time.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan  This was one of our star students.  We all (faculty and staff both) knew her, and we *knew* we were going to admit her, but she had to make the request in order to have her transcript on file.  (This was a state school in the U.S.  There's a specific exception to FERPA for schools to which one has applied, but we still required that request.)